# Using WebSphereUowTransactionManager in a stand alone application

Tags: java, spring, transactions, jta

I want to use "WebSphereUowTransactionManager" of Spring  for transaction managemnt in a  simple stand alone java application . Is it possible ?

Comment: No, it will only work with the Websphere libraries available. Why do you want to use it in a standalone application?

Comment: I was just testing this transaction manager for my test cases.What if I make available Websphere libraries(WAS JRE Jars) in the build path of the application.Will it work. I was thinking that it will take less time to test my test cases in stand alone application than web application , thats why I was testing it in stand alone app.